# Quick binary encoding

Tags: linux, encoding

I'm working in linux on some homework and I cant seem to find anything online of what exactly the encoding actually means on MIPS instructions... I have used objdump -d to obtain a file that reads out, for example, lines like this:

68 90 8b 04 08          push   $0x8048b90

what do each of the bytes in the first part mean? I assume the las four have to to with the actual register being pushed, but any help would be appreciated, or even a link to somewhere I could look up this kind of stuff because I cannot find it

Comment: What you're seeing is the dump of the file as if it were x86 instructions, not MIPS instructions. If the file is really a MIPS file, you need a version of objdump that can dump MIPS instructions.

Comment: See, for example, http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html